# How to insert hive data to Teradata Table using spark-shell

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, teradata

I am trying to export `saprkSQL` query output to Teradata. I am able to connect teradata from spark using JDBC driver and run some queries on already existing tables in Teradata, but I am unable to figure out how can I insert data that I received from my spark sql(Hive query output) to a teradata Table

This what I used to connect

```
val jdbcDF = sqlContext.load("jdbc", Map(
      "url" -> "jdbc:teradata://******/database=****, 
      TMODE=TERA, 
      user=****, 
      password=*****",
      "dbtable" -> "(select count(*) as t from table) as ST",
      "driver" -> "com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver")
)
```